# I need to check the dateTime with the null using XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a xml like below which are of type "dateTime"

I/p:

```
<dates>
<CompletedDate>2018-01-03T00:00:00.000+01:00</CompletedDate>
<ENDDate>2017-01-03T00:00:00.000+01:00</ENDDate>
</dates>
```

O/p:

```
<projectEnd>2017-01-03T00:00:00.000+01:00</projectEnd>
```

By using XSLT, i need to implement the logic like if ENDDate is null i need to assign CompletedDate to projectEnd, if the ENDDate has value then this value should go to projectEnd.

I used like this, but it not working, it is always taking "CompletedDate":

```
<xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="ENDDate != null">
          <tns:projectEnd>
            <xsl:value-of select="ENDDate"/>
          </tns:projectEnd>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <tns:projectEnd>
            <xsl:value-of select="CompletedDate"/>
          </tns:projectEnd>
          </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Can someone help me how to compare the dateTime data type with the null?

Regards,
Vishnu

Comment: There is no `null` in XSLT. Test for  `ENDDate` being empty or not existing altogether (which one you need is not clear from your question).

Comment: Hello Michael,Thanks for you comment, anyways i found the solution to test for the existence of the data in the tag by using "ENDDate[text()]".